# How to load/not load pagination depending if objects exists? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to make it so that my pagination only shows up if there are posts on the page and there can be only posts, if the admin has approved them.

If there are no posts, there should be "No posts to show" shown on the template,if there are approved posts, then the posts should be shown and also the pagination options.

What am I doing wrong here?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView,
    CreateView,
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView
)
from .models import Post


def market(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'userMarket/market.html', context)


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'userMarket/market.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
    paginate_by = 5


class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'userMarket/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user).order_by('-date_posted')


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'content']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False


class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = '/market'

    def test_func(self):
        post = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user == post.author:
            return True
        return False
```

**market.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <!-- Posts Layout -->
    <div class="col-sm">
        {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.approved == True %}
        <div class="card my-4">
            <div class="card-content">
                <article class="media content-section my-2">
                    <img class="rounded-circle article-img my-2" src="{{ post.author.profile.image.url }}">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="article-metadata">
                            <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user-posts' post.author.username %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
                        </div>
                        <h3><a class="article-title ml-1" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        {% if posts == None and post.approved == False %}
        <h3>No posts available</h3>
        {% else %}
        <!-- Pagination part-->
        <div class="mt-4">
            {% if is_paginated %}

            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
               <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page=1">First</a>
               <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if page_obj.number == num %}
               <a class="btn btn-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
               <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ num }}">{{ num }}</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}

            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
               <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
               <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
            {% endif %}

            {% endif %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 my-4">
        <div class="content-section">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Create Post</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing that is to override the `get_queryset` method of your view, to *pass* only approved posts to the template:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    # ...
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(approved=True)
```

and in your template:

```
{% for post in page_obj %}
    <!-- .... -->
{% empty %}
    <h1>No posts!</h1>
{% endfor %}

{% if is_paginated %}
    <!-- pagination code goes here -->
{% endif %}
```

and you don't need the `{% if post.approved %}` anymore as only approved posts are passed to the tempalte.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this kind of an approach is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Try `{% if posts.all %}`. It works for me